# How to apply constraints to multiple line labels in StoryBoard?

Tags: ios

I have static data on my Screen. I have taken labels to display it, but when I am going to apply constraints on it for iPhone 6 then it displays data in single line at preview screen. Please send me solution which constraints I have to add.

Comment: could you be elaborate with your code?

Comment: Did you set label's 'Lines' property to 0 in storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. Set height constraint for multiple label
2. Select it throw builder
3. Change 'Relation' property to 'Greater Than or Equal' (to automatically resize content depend on text)
4. Set 'Lines' property of target label to '0'

like so

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to provide each element's height,width,x-position,and y-position.

If you are not sure, just drag the elements to wherever you want them to be (be careful about those alignments), and use 'Add Missing Constraints' or 'Reset to Suggested Constraints'.

[image: Add Missing Constraints]

Though I highly don't recommend using them, you may end up manually modifying the constraints by yourself.

You need to be more specific so that we can offer more help.

Comment: My label's size is 12, 144, 308, 36. The text display in iPhone 6 is just a single line (Incomplete).

Comment: Yes, that's why I say you may end up manually modifying the constraints. Perhaps some constraint requires the height to be 36, instead of what it is supposed to be. You need to inspect the constraints individually, and make sure they are what you really want.